# Can you use but after because to reinforce the predicate following because?

Tags: grammar

The animal was classified into that category temporarily, because there weren't any good category for it, but some experts agreed to put it there for various scientific reasons.

I am wondering if the above sentence is correct, because I've never seen but augment the preceding clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"...there weren't any good category for it..."

The above phrase is not correct.  Correct:

There weren't any good categories for it
or
There wasn't a good category for it. (need parallel construction)

Here is how I would write the text:
The animal was classified into that category temporarily, because there wasn't any good category for it.  But, some experts agreed to put it there for various scientific reasons.
   however,

I don't think the other sentence is wrong, just a little wordy. I'm not a linguist, but I am a plain English writer.

Good luck.

Comment: Your final suggested sentence would read better with either **but** or **however** - not both.

Comment: +1 But please, no comma after *But*. It's a conjunction, not a disjunction.

Comment: can you put it on one sentence?